# ASP.NET DropDownList not getting correct SelectedItem

Tags: asp.net, rest, gridview, drop-down-menu

We are using ASP.NET for one of our projects. However, when we are trying to read the SelectedItem or SelectedValue property of the DropDownList we are using in the callback function of a Link click, we are not getting the correct SelectedItem.

```
<FooterTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="cmbTesters" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Width="300px" DataSource='<%# PopulateTesterNames() %>' DataTextField="FullName" DataValueField = "PK_ID"></asp:DropDownList>
</FooterTemplate>
```

This is the DropDownList in the aspx file. The drop down is present within a GridView's Footer Row. We are invoking the following set of code on clicking a link.

```
  if (int.TryParse(((DropDownList)dgCreateCPRVerificationResponse.FooterRow.FindControl("cmbTesters")).SelectedValue, out TesterID))
  {
   TesterID = int.Parse(((DropDownList)dgCreateCPRVerificationResponse.FooterRow.FindControl("cmbTesters")).SelectedValue);
  }
```

The problem we are facing is that whatever value we choose, the SelectedValue is always of the first item in the list. We are using REST based URL defined in the global.asax file. Also note that this is not built on any framework.

Please help as soon as possible

Comment: Have you check the **postback**?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put the binding methods of the dropdownlist and the gridview inside `if (!IsPostBack)`